# upload a file with persian name in liferay 6.2 portlet on centos linux server

Tags: java, file, file-upload, utf-8, liferay

In my **custom liferay6.2 portlet**, I have a form for **uploading files** on the folder in my **CentOS linux server**. 
Each time that I upload a file with persian name, it uploads **successfully** **but** after that I check destination folder in server I see that the name file becomes change and instead the exact name in persian language some strange characters replace on the main name.

**for example my file name is **`نحوه ورود به سیستم.doc`**
but after upload, I checked the folder on the server and I see that this file uploaded with this name :
`طµظ†ط¯ظˆظ‚ ط³ط±ظ…ط§ظٹظ‡ ع¯ط°ط§ط±ظٹ ط¨ط§ ط¯ط±ط¢ظ…ط¯ ط«ط§ط¨طھ ظƒظˆط«ط± ظٹظƒظ….doc`**

### How can I solve this issue?

### This is my view.jsp page

---

```
    <%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2000-2013 Liferay, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under
 * the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by the Free
 * Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option)
 * any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT
 * ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS
 * FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU Lesser General Public License for more
 * details.
 */
%>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/theme.css">
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/jalali.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/calendar.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/calendar-setup.js"></script>
<script src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/js/calendar-fa.js"></script>



<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="liferay-ui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="aui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/aui" %>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  -->

<style type="text/css">
    fieldset {
        border: 1px solid #CCCCCC !important;
        margin: 10px 10px 14px !important;
        padding: 10px !important;
    }
    .aui legend {
        display: block;
        width: auto !important;
        padding: 0 10px !important;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 19.5px;
        line-height: 40px;
        color: #333;
        border: 0;
        border-bottom: 0px none !important;
    }
    .aui-field-label { width: 190px; float: right; }

    [class~="aui-form-validator-message"] { position: relative !important; height: 20px; }

    .aui-field-eblagh-date          .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-eblagh-subject       .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-eblagh-type          .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-shenaseh-num         .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-doc-code             .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-baznegari-num        .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-eblagh-status        .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-process-owner        .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-eblagh-validity      .form-validator-stack,
    .aui-field-attachment-file      .form-validator-stack
    { display: none; }


    select.error-field { border-color: #990000; border-style: dashed; }

    .aui-field-eblagh-date          .error-field,
    .aui-field-eblagh-subject       .error-field,
    .aui-field-shenaseh-num         .error-field,
    .aui-field-doc-code             .error-field,
    .aui-field-baznegari-num        .error-field {
        border-color: #990000 !important;
    }

    .aui-field-attachment-file      .error-field {
        border-color: #990000 !important;
        border: 1px solid;
    }

    .aui-form-validator-error-container { color: #000000 !important; }
    .aui-field-label span { color: #ff0000; }

    .bottuns { padding-top: 20px; float: left; }

</style>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate()
    {
        var attachment_file =document.getElementById("attachment_file").value;
        if(attachment_file!='')
        {
            var checkFile = attachment_file.toLowerCase();
            var file = document.getElementById("attachment_file");
            if(file.files[0].size > 53477376) // validation according to file size
            {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="حجم سند مورد نظر، بیشتر از 50 مگابایت می باشد.";
                return false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById("errorMsg").innerHTML="<img src='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/Success-icon.png' />";
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->


<%
    if(request.getAttribute("error_file_exist") != null)
    {
        out.print("<ul>");
        out.print("<li>");
        out.print("سندی با این نام وجود دارد، لطفاً نام سند خود را تغییر داده و مجدداً تلاش نمایید.");
        out.print("</li>");
        out.print("</ul>");
    }
    else if (request.getAttribute("error_file_size") != null)
    {
        out.print("<ul>");
        out.print("<li>");
        out.print("حجم سند انتخابی زیاد می باشد.");
        out.print("</li>");
        out.print("</ul>");
    }
    else if (request.getAttribute("success_msg") != null)
    {
        out.print("<p>");
        out.print("<img src='/upload-file-portlet/images/Success-icon.png' />");
        out.print("<span style='font-size: 14px; padding-right: 10px;'>");
        out.print("سند مورد نظر با موفقیت اضافه گردید.");
        out.print("</span>");
        out.print("</p>");
    }
%>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->


<portlet:defineObjects />
<portlet:actionURL var="myUrl">
</portlet:actionURL>




<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<%= myUrl %>" method="POST" name="fm" id="fm" onChange="Validate()">
<div id="page-wrap">
<div id="tabs">
<fieldset>
    <legend>مشخصات فایل ارسالی</legend>
    <p class="aui-field-eblagh-date">
        <label class="aui-field-label">تاریخ ابلاغ :<span>*</span></label>
        <input name="eblagh_date" id="eblagh_date"  autocomplete="off" type="text" /><img id="date_btn_1" src="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/images/cal.png" style="vertical-align: top;" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Calendar.setup({
                inputField     :    "eblagh_date",   // id of the input field
                button         :    "date_btn_1",   // trigger for the calendar (button ID)
                ifFormat       :    "%Y-%m-%d",       // format of the input field
                dateType       :    'jalali',
                weekNumbers    : false
            });
        </script>
    </p>
    <p class="aui-field-eblagh-subject">
        <label class="aui-field-label">موضوع ابلاغیه :<span>*</span></label>
        <input name="eblagh_subject" type="text" />
    </p>
    <p class="aui-field-eblagh-type">
        <label class="aui-field-label">نوع ابلاغیه :<span>*</span></label>
        <select id="eblagh_type" name="eblagh_type">
            <option value="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="فرم">فرم</option>
            <option value="دستورالعمل">دستورالعمل</option>
            <option value="روش اجرایی">روش اجرایی</option>
            <option value="بخشنامه">بخشنامه</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p class="aui-field-shenaseh-num">
        <label class="aui-field-label">شماره شناسه :<span>*</span></label>
        <input name="shenaseh_num" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p class="aui-field-doc-code">
        <label class="aui-field-label">کد مدرک :<span>*</span></label>
        <input name="doc_code" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p class="aui-field-baznegari-num">
        <label class="aui-field-label">شماره بازنگری :<span></span></label>
        <input name="baznegari_num" type="text" />
    </p>

    <p class="aui-field-eblagh-status">
        <label class="aui-field-label">ماهیت ابلاغیه :<span>*</span></label>
        <select id="eblagh_status" name="eblagh_status">
            <option value="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="عملیاتی">عملیاتی</option>
            <option value="غیر عملیاتی">غیرعملیاتی</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p class="aui-field-process-owner">
        <label class="aui-field-label">مالک فرآیند :<span>*</span></label>
        <select id="process_owner" name="process_owner">
            <option value="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="صندوق">صندوق</option>
            <option value="تسهیلات">تسهیلات</option>
            <option value="حسابداری">حسابداری</option>
            <option value="مسئول IT">مسئول IT</option>
            <option value="سایر">سایر</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p class="aui-field-eblagh-validity">
        <label class="aui-field-label">اعتبار ابلاغیه :<span>*</span></label>
        <select id="eblagh_validity" name="eblagh_validity">
            <option value="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="جاری">جاری</option>
            <option value="آرشیو">آرشیو</option>
        </select>
    </p>

    <p class="aui-field-attachment-file">
        <label class="aui-field-label">ضمیمه :<span>*</span></label>
        <input name="attachment_file" id="attachment_file" type="file" />
        <span id="errorMsg" style="position: relative; right: 1%; color: red; font-size: 14px;"></span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="ذخیره" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
</div>
</div>
</form>

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<!-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -->

<aui:script>

    AUI().ready('aui-form-validator', 'aui-overlay-context-panel', function(A) {

        var validator2 = new A.FormValidator({
        boundingBox: document.fm,

            fieldContainer: 'p',
            rules: {
            eblagh_date: {
                required: true
            },
            eblagh_subject: {
                required: true,
                rangeLength: [2,100]
            },
            eblagh_type: {
                required: true
            },
            shenaseh_num: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            doc_code: {
                required: true
            },
            baznegari_num: {
                digits: true
            },
            eblagh_status: {
                required: true
            },
            process_owner: {
                required: true
            },
            eblagh_validity: {
                required: true
            },
            attachment_file: {
                required: true
            }
        },

            on: {
                submitError: function(event) {
                    var formEvent = event.validator.formEvent;
                    var errors = event.validator.errors;
                },

                submit: function(event) {
                    var formEvent = event.validator.formEvent;
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });

</aui:script>
```

---

---

### This is my JSPPortlet.jsp page {Generic portlet}

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Liferay, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
 *
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
 *
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
 * SOFTWARE.
 */

package com.sample.jsp.portlet;


import com.ghasemkiani.util.icu.PersianDateFormat;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionMessages;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.upload.UploadPortletRequest;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.FileUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.util.PortalUtil;
import kosar.dao.uploadFileDao;
import kosar.model.uploadFileModel;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;


import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.portlet.*;

/**
 * <a href="JSPPortlet.java.html"><b><i>View Source</i></b></a>
 *
 * @author Brian Wing Shun Chan
 *
 */
public class JSPPortlet extends GenericPortlet {

    protected String realPath=null;

    /**
     * Helper method to serve up the mandatory view mode.
     */
    protected void doView(RenderRequest request, RenderResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {
        PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();




            PortletRequestDispatcher dispatcher = getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/view.jsp");
            dispatcher.include(request, response);
    }


    /**
     * Called by the portlet container to allow the portlet to process an action request.
     * This method is called if the client request was originated by a URL created
     * (by the portlet) with the RenderResponse.createActionURL() method.
     */
    public void processAction(ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
            throws PortletException, IOException {
        PortletPreferences prefs = request.getPreferences();
        UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest = PortalUtil.getUploadPortletRequest(request);



        //convert Jalali to Gregorian
        PersianDateFormat persianDateFormat = new PersianDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date eblaghDate = null;
        try {
            eblaghDate = persianDateFormat.parse(uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("eblagh_date"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(eblaghDate);
        System.out.println("convert Jalali to Gregorian");
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
        System.out.println(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));




        String source= calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println("source : " + source);




        String gregorian_eblagh_date = source;
        java.util.Date date = null;
        try {
            date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(gregorian_eblagh_date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());
        System.out.println(sqlDate);


            String folder=getInitParameter("uploadFolder");

            String eblagh_subject = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("eblagh_subject");
            String eblagh_type = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("eblagh_type");
            String shenaseh_num = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("shenaseh_num");
            String doc_code = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("doc_code");
            String baznegari_num= uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("baznegari_num");
            String eblagh_status = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("eblagh_status");
            String process_owner = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("process_owner");
            String eblagh_validity = uploadPortletRequest.getParameter("eblagh_validity");
            String attachment_addr;
            String sourceFileName_attach = uploadPortletRequest.getFileName("attachment_file");
            String ext = FilenameUtils.getExtension(sourceFileName_attach);

            System.out.println("!!!!!!!!! -----> " + ext);

            uploadFileModel fileModel = new uploadFileModel();
            fileModel.setEblagh_date(sqlDate);
            fileModel.setEblagh_subject(eblagh_subject);
            fileModel.setEblagh_type(eblagh_type);
            fileModel.setShenaseh_num(shenaseh_num);
            fileModel.setDoc_code(doc_code);
            fileModel.setBaznegari_num(baznegari_num);
            fileModel.setEblagh_status(eblagh_status);
            fileModel.setProcess_owner(process_owner);
            fileModel.setEblagh_validity(eblagh_validity);
            fileModel.setFile_name(sourceFileName_attach);
            fileModel.setFile_extension(ext);

            if (sourceFileName_attach != null && sourceFileName_attach != "") {
                attachment_addr =  folder + sourceFileName_attach;
            }
            else {
                attachment_addr = "*****************";
            }

            try {
                if (AddFile(request,uploadPortletRequest) == true) {
                    uploadFileDao fileDao = new uploadFileDao();
                    fileDao.addFileInfo(fileModel, attachment_addr);
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Sorry, Try Again !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! - (AddFile)");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }

    }





    /* ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ */

    public boolean AddFile(ActionRequest request, UploadPortletRequest uploadPortletRequest) throws Exception{
        boolean result = false;
        String folder=getInitParameter("uploadFolder");
        realPath = getPortletContext().getRealPath("/");
        byte[] bytes = null;
        String sourceFileName = uploadPortletRequest.getFileName("attachment_file");
        File file = uploadPortletRequest.getFile("attachment_file");
        long size = uploadPortletRequest.getSize("attachment_file");

        System.out.println("############ ---> " + size);
        bytes = FileUtil.getBytes(file);
        File newFile = null;
        if ((bytes == null)) { result = true; }
        if ((bytes != null) && (bytes.length > 0)) {

            try {
                //sourceFileName = URLEncoder.encode(sourceFileName,"UTF-8");
                System.out.println("----------> " + sourceFileName);
                newFile = new File(folder+sourceFileName);
                // 51 Mb  =  53477376 byte
                if(newFile.exists()){
                    System.out.println("File Exsist, Try again !!!");
                    request.setAttribute("error_file_exist","File Exsist, Try again !!!");

                }
                else if (size > 53477376) {
                    System.out.println("file size is too large!!!");
                    request.setAttribute("error_file_size", "file size is too large!!!");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("photo-address ----------> " + folder + sourceFileName);
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                    fileInputStream.read(bytes);
                    fileOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                    fileOutputStream.close();
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    SessionMessages.add(request, "success");
                    result = true;
                    request.setAttribute("success_msg", "File added successfully.");

                }
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("File Not Found.");
                e.printStackTrace();
                SessionMessages.add(request, "error");
            }
            catch (IOException e1){
                System.out.println("Error Reading The File.");
                e1.printStackTrace();
                SessionMessages.add(request, "error");
            }
        }
        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site

Answer (score 0):

Place this as first lines of `processAction` method

```
HttpServletRequest req = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(request);
req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

Also note that [ServletRequest#setCharacterEncoding](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setCharacterEncoding-java.lang.String-)

> must be called prior to reading request parameters or reading input
>   using getReader(). Otherwise, it has no effect.

So if `processAction` is not first method who reads request then `setCharacterEncoding` must be called in other place.